# Migrating SQL Server CE data to Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to update my Windows Phone app from using Silverlight to Windows Runtime so as to use the new *universal* application approach.

There's a huge problem though: in Silverlight there is integrated support for SQL Server CE through `System.Data.Linq`. I like it very much, but apparently this code is not available in Windows Runtime. Actually, there appears to be no native support for any kind of database in WinRT, but people are happy using the [sqlite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/1.0.8) NuGet package for this purpose.

So, even if I used *sqlite-net*, there's still a problem - users will already have the data in SQL Server CE format when the app is updated - how then am I going to convert the data from SQL Server CE to SQLite so that I would be able to access it in Windows Runtime?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this on a device, so you must move the SQL CE database elsewhere for conversion to sqlite, and the get hold of the converted database and put it back on the device. Some kind of web service should be able to do this non-trivial task.